# How to extract the year without it being repeated

Tags: postgresql

Hello colleagues I have a question about a query if it could be done I have a table called sale and a field called sales_date, so the field is full more or less like this

```
--------------------------------------------------
sales_date
--------------------------------------------------
2013-02-03
2013-02-05
2014-06-07
2015-03-04
2015-01-04
2016-04-07
2016-09-03
2016-04-09
```

And I would like to know how to do a select and show me only the years without repeating

```
 --------------------------------------------------
 sales_date
 --------------------------------------------------
 2013
 2014
 2015
 2016
```

Thanks any help, my database is in Postgresql version 9.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`extract()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) to get the year and `distinct` to remove the duplicates:

```
select distinct extract(year from sales_date) as sales_date
from sale;
```